# Visual Studio - Feedback websocket connection error

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have become unable to provide feedback on visual studio 2022.
I'm running the preview version 17.6 p1, but this has been going on for a few VS preview versions. I have also tried reporting feedback on a non-preview version (17.4) but same result, I assume they rely upon the same background websocket service.

I would typically post Visual Studio related issues on their feedback channel, but it is actually impossible to post feedback if the local feedback websocket doesn't connect.

I have tried using both firefox and edge with the same result and console errors.

Various browser Console errors:

`WebSocket connection timed out after 10 seconds`

`Received platform event: CLIENTERROR`

Any thoughts on how I can troubleshoot this? There isn't much to go on.

Comment: Try disabling IPV6 for your network adapters, I've had this issue with VS in the past, and this proved to resolve it (for me).

Comment: well that worked for me too. weird bug. the websocket is even using 127.0.0.1 and not localhost - so you'd think that would address the issue. anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: now i just need to remember what feedback i was going to report 

Comment: I've added this as an answer, would be good to submit this issue to MS again, I've seen this issue posted before on the VS Community Forum, but they usually get closed as "Not enough info" or "Can't reproduce". Hence the issue is still kicking around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio has had an issue for a while now where various remote connections to Feedback, Manage Extensions and Marketplace will fail with Websocket timeout errors when IPv6 is enable. I have seen this mostly when using wireless adapters.

To resolve the issue simply disable the IPv6 settings for your adapters.

Comment: Thank you! You've saved many hairs this day.